# Calculating fields on quarterly and yearly basis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have this code on Oracle Apex 11.1:

```
select r.s_manager_id,r.s_manager_nam,count(distinct(emp_id))Total_Employees,
    round((SUM(decode(bcoe,'y',1,0))/count(bcoe))*100,2)||'%'bcoe,
    round((SUM(decode(ecp,'y',1,0))/count(ecp))*100,2)||'%'ecp,
    round((SUM(decode(leave,'y',1,0))/count(leave))*100,2)||'%'leave,
    round((SUM(decode(eud,'y',1,0))/count(eud))*100,2)||'%'eud,
    round((SUM(decode(parking,'y',1,0))/count(parking))*100,2)||'%'parking,
    round((SUM(decode(building,'y',1,0))/count(building))*100,2)||'%'building
    from s_manager r,cmanager c,compliancetype t
    where r.s_manager_id = c.s_manager_id
        AND c.s_manager_id = t.s_manager_id
        AND month = 'Feb'
     GROUP BY r.s_manager_id,r.s_manager_nam
```

It calculates different types of compliances, but `ecp` and `bcoe` are supposed to be calculated on a yearly basis. How to do that in Oracle Apex? Then `leave` is supposed to be calculated quarterly; how to do that?

Comment: You're selecting for a particular month; are you expecting the fields to show the total for the quarter (or year) that month falls in, with the rest specific to the single month? If so you might want to look at [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm).

Comment: Yes it is done on oracle application express,i have created my tables and running the query on oracle apex

Comment: This link also might be useful http://orafaq.com/node/55 for understanding Analytic functions

Answer (score 0):

Each of these

```
round((SUM(decode(FIELD,'y',1,0))/count(FIELD))*100,2)||'%'FIELD
```

can be simplified to

```
round(AVG(decode(FIELD,'y',1,0))*100,2)||'%'FIELD
```

For Quarterly/Yearly, if the year data you want to show is within `month = 'Dec'` and the quarter data in the monts of March, June and so on then you won't need to go to Analytics.

Simply wrap the calculated field in this way for quarterly data.

```
case when month in ('Mar', 'Jun', 'Sep', 'Dec') then 
     round(AVG(decode(leave,'y',1,0))*100,2)||'%'leave
else 0
end
```